# Auto-imports or other code-less way of using custom functions

Tags: python, function, methods

I have written the odd handy function while I've been doing python. (A few methods on lists, couple of more useful input functions ect.)

What I want is to be able to access these functions from a python file without having to import a module through `import my_module`.

The way I though it would happen is automatically importing a module, or putting these functions in another default python module, but I don't really mind how it's done.

Can anyone shed some light on how I should do this?

(I know `import my_module` is not a lot, but you could end up with

```
sys.path.append("c:\fake\path")
from my_module import *
```

which is getting long...)

Comment: Don't, as explicit is better than implicit!

Comment: Yeah, but it gets annoying...

Comment: if you use `iPython`, you can set it up to automatically import things.

Comment: @Andrew I don't, but I could...

Comment: This will make your code unmaintainable, and rather sooner than later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The python module [`site`](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) is imported automatically whenever the python interpreter is run. This module attempts to import another, named `sitecustomize`. You could put your functions in there, adding them to the [`__builtins__` mapping](http://docs.python.org/library/__builtin__.html) with:

```
for func in [foo, bar, baz]:
    __builtins__[func.__name__] = func
```

Note that this only works on cpython, where `__builtins__` is a mutable dict. Doing so will automatically make these functions available to all your python code for this installation.

**I *strongly* would discourage you from doing so!** Implicit is never better than explicit, and anyone maintaining your code will wonder where the *hell* these came from.

You'd be better off with a `from myglobalutils import *` import in your modules.

Answer (score 1):

See `import this` (it says a lot in a few lines). You can `import` a module which has imported the the other ones, for example:

```
import my.main # where main.py contains `import X, Y, Z`

# X, Y, and Z access:
my.main.X
my.main.Y
my.main.Z
```

Comment: I see what you're saying about importing modules from modules, but what do you mean by `import this`?

Comment: @ACarter: open a python interpreter prompt and try it.